# Change the path to files in library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible in the library to change/update the path of all resources at the same time?

Usually I change each file one-at-a-time using the *update* command.

Answer (score 0):

Files in the library are copied into the .fla file. So there is actually no path to change. There is some metadata that stores where that file originated (which is what is used when doing the 'update' option in the library).   As far as I know there is no bulk update option available.

However, there is a bit of a hack/workaround you could do.   An FLA file is actually a zip file.  So if you change it's extension to .zip, and uncompress it, you'll see a library folder.  In that folder are all the library assets you've created/imported.  You could copy and paste updated files all at once into that folder.

Then just run the `xfl` file (which is the real flash project file) from that point on.  Or try and reconmpress it back to a zip file and change the extension back to .fla